# Regular expression - from the string "100 U.S. Dolar 1196.3280" is necessary to select "1196.3280"

Tags: regex

Please help make the regular expression to find the last digit of the string

```
 100 U.S. Dolar 1196.3280
```

need to allocate 1196.3280

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting what is at the end of the string, use the end of string `$` anchor.

```
\S+$
```

`\S` matches any non-white space character. ( [Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT2zO8/2) )

If you need to match that specific pattern at the end of the string:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT2zO8/3)

If you are needing to match floats, then look at the answer that @dawg provided.

Comment: This will match any combo of digits and periods, such as `1.2.3.4` and `.......22.2` etc.

Comment: @dawg, I understand that. OP was not specific about anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a floating point at the end of a string, use something like

`[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/xG6eQ5/1)